# How to fix androidX issues with Flutter plugins?

Tags: android, flutter, android-jetpack

I have a flutter project. Inside of its "android" folder I have a lot of android code. I updated this code to use the new androidX packages.

Now, some of the plugins stopepd working. A example is the `permission_handler` plugin.

```
permissionhandler\PermissionHandlerPlugin.kt: (10, 31): Unresolved reference: ActivityCompat
permissionhandler\PermissionHandlerPlugin.kt: (11, 27): Unresolved reference: content
permissionhandler\PermissionHandlerPlugin.kt: (152, 37): Unresolved reference: ContextCompat
permissionhandler\PermissionHandlerPlugin.kt: (191, 20): Unresolved reference: ActivityCompat
permissionhandler\PermissionHandlerPlugin.kt: (235, 13): Unresolved reference: ActivityCompat
```

This is probably caused by the removal of old support library and upgrading it to the new androidX.
How to fix this ?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I changed to master channel and it worked but on the stable channel it doesn't work `flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6`

Answer (score 0):

Flutter doesn't officially support AndroidX, but [it's on their todo list](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23586).

You'd have to make updates to the plugins themselves to use AndroidX (which I've done for a few items).

Comment: It does now and this error still occurs on the stable branch